# Functors that have a natural Isomorphism

Tags: logic, ring-theory, category-theory

Find different functors $T, S: Rng \rightarrow Rng$ both identity on objects IE: for each ring $R, T(R)=S(R)=R$, such that there is a natural isomorphism between T and S.

I know that a natural transformation $ \tau : S \rightarrow T$ with every component $\tau r$ (where $ r \in$ Rng) invertible in Rng is called a natural isomorphism.

Comment: What do you mean by $Rng$? For instance, the identity functor on the category of unital commutative rings has no interesting automorphisms.

Comment: @ZhenLin Rng = Ring.

Comment: @Zhen: The point is that $T,S$ don't have to be the identity functor.